# flush() method of printwriter doesnt work

Tags: java

I am trying to write to a file, which another process can read. I am using the Printwiter to write to a file. But it doesnt write to the file as long as i dont terminate the program. I have eanbles the autflush on, and even explicitly flusing. The code is below -

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


         try {

              // Create a print writer
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\SpringProjects\\RescilienceModel\\natural_resource.txt");
              //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
              PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

              // Experiment with some methods
              while(true)
              {
              pw.println(99);
              pw.flush();
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you check that nothing is written to the file?  It should be working the way you are expecting.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to the issue at hand, but it is probably worth noticing that the documentation for [Writer.flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush()) reads  __"If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive."__

Comment: It's already problematic to write & read to/from a file the same time. The OS might buffer, cache and load old data until you close the handle and signal an update. Rather use shared memory, pipes or blocking files for this kind of job.

Comment: @Youka: *"The OS might cache and load old data until you close the handle."*: Can you back up that claim?

Comment: So what you suggest to use ? I need a memory  area/file where one process will write and the other will read from it ..

Comment: Use a socket. Files are a poor substitute for proper IPC mechanisms.

Comment: @Youka What exactly is a 'blocking file'?

Comment: how about PipedReader and PipedWriter ?

Comment: @EJP To be more exactly, i mean file locking. The access to the file should be blocked until other operations are done.

Comment: @sstan Like creating an index for faster searching, i read a paper some years ago about caching small file directories for fast access on often read files, like configurations. Not sure if this found his way in some OS, was just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues.

1. Check that while(true) loop, or it won't end.
2. close() your handle, or it won't release resources.

Comment: Though true, it doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: and 3. Use try with resource if using `Java - 7+`